# MD5 hashes not the same

Tags: actionscript-3, hash, md5

EDIT: I have found some other hashes which this approach works on as well

```
c1542f06532950d9-c50fd90a80c8017a-6dcef1027f806329
9fc13754516e58d9-c50fd90a80c8017a-77e823d4b2b89ab4
206692e64d4a33b6-c50fd90a80c8017a-e04a839a7546fab3
7ed6b64f4e0cbfa7-c50fd90a80c8017a-147436e4f7955553
```

and are clearly not the same so the onlything I can think of it is that its could be an encoding issue (not sure if you can specify string encoding in AS3 or is it always UTF8)

Hi I have 2 strings which I am trying to get MD5 hash from

```
string1 = "c1542f06532950d9-c50fd90a80c8017a-6dcef1027f806329";
```

first I convert it into an array

```
myArray1 = string1.split('-');
```

then I get the value I want to compare to MD5 calculation from it

```
value1 = String(myArray1.pop()); (6dcef1027f806329 - value I am comparing to)
```

and then I calculate MD5 so I can compare it to value1

```
MD52Compare = MD5.hash(string1.slice(0,-16 -1) + "fours4me").substr(0,16); (6dcef1027f806329 - I get the same value as value1 which is what I want)
```

Then I tried the same with a seond string

```
string2 = "f7a45ced624d3a70-1df5b7cd427370f7-b91ee21d6cb22d7b";
```

again converting it into an array

```
myArray2 = string2.split('-');
```

I get the value for comparing to exacly the same way

```
value2 = String(myArray2.pop()); (b91ee21d6cb22d7b - value I am comparing to)
```

now as before I calculate MD5

```
MD52Compare2 = MD5.hash(string2.slice(0,-16 -1) + "fours4me").substr(0,16); (03358d45ac9ed391 - and here is the problem MD52Compare2 is != value2)
```

so I am not sure why second string doesn't produce the same MD5 value
I also tried with this string:

```
9c1687ea58e5e770-1df5b7cd427370f7-4b62a84526ea1f56
```

and again I can't compare MD5 to last value of it
so I am not realy sure what is happening here do theese 3 strings differ

BTW: I am using adobe crypto: https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib/blob/master/src/com/adobe/crypto/MD5.as to get MD5 hash

Thanks for Anwsering and Best Regards

Comment: What's the question? Two different strings often have different hash.

Comment: the question is why do the hashes differ (they shouldn't) (because why did I get the same hash on 1 string then?)

Comment: @user3368585 I think you misunderstand something about MD5 hash. **MD5.hash(A) == MD5.hash(B)** only if **A == B**. Since you're taking hashes from different strings, you get different results.

Comment: OK if 6dcef1027f806329 is MD5("c1542f06532950d9-c50fd90a80c8017a" + "fours4me").substr(0,16) how do you get 4b62a84526ea1f56 then?

Comment: @user3368585 Ok, I dig it a bit and now understand what you are doing there. It is exactly as you say, the last piece of the first string is MD5 hash that is calculated the way you provided. Strings 2 and 3 do not match that algorithm. I checked with MD5 from **as3corelib** and got exactly the same results as you got, so it's not an MD5 problem. It's either algorithm is not what you think it is, or strings 2 and 3 are (intentionally or not) broken.

Comment: hmm you are right is it posible to reverse MD5 so I can see what b91ee21d6cb22d7b in fact is, because b91ee21d6cb22d7b is MD5 (at least this: https://github.com/psypanda/hashID told me it is)

Comment: @user3368585 No, the very idea of hash (MD5 or SHA1 or whatever) is that it is irreversible.

Comment: now the question remains: how was 4b62a84526ea1f56 hashed?

Comment: @user3368585 No idea. Without actual and exact algorithm there's no telling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for anyone interested the problem was that I didn't use the right string to calculate md5 with

this

```
string1 = "c1542f06532950d9-c50fd90a80c8017a-6dcef1027f806329";    
MD52Compare2 = MD5.hash(string1.slice(0,-16 -1) + "fours4me").substr(0,16);
```

should actualy be

```
string2 = "f7a45ced624d3a70-1df5b7cd427370f7-b91ee21d6cb22d7b";    
MD52Compare2 = MD5.hash(string2.slice(0,-16 -1) + "aXPB2").substr(0,16);
```

for second string

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: For the new question:
Convert the exact strings you're trying to get an MD5 on to hexadecimal, and you'll see where they are different.  Guaranteed, they're different.

EDIT: The below references the original question.
The second doesn't match because you're not using the right array variable.

> myArray1 = string1.split('-');
>   value1 = String(myArray1.pop()); (6dcef1027f806329 - value I am comparing to)

vs

> myArray2 = string2.split('-');
>   value2 = String(myArray.pop()); (b91ee21d6cb22d7b - value I am comparing to)

The latter should be

value2 = String(**myArray2**.pop()); (b91ee21d6cb22d7b - value I am comparing to)

Where did "myArray" come from?

Also, please **quit using MD5** - it's vulnerable to collisions, and generally too small.  Use a member of the SHA-2 or SHA-3 family or Whirlpool instead; all of these were [accepted by NESSIE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NESSIE#MAC_algorithms_and_cryptographic_hash_functions).

If you're doing password hashing, quit using any raw hash and move to pbkdf2, bcrypt, scrypt, or argon2.

Comment: whoopy my mistake I meant myArray2 = string2.split('-'); value2 = String(myArray2.pop()); (seems a typo occurred when typing the question) 
I edited the question so it reflect the change

Comment: Convert your strings that you're hashing to hex; you'll see the difference clearly then.